# Relationships midst two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table `visitors` and table `users`. Each visitor can be created by only one user and contains field `visitors.userId`.

So, any another user from table `users` can edit or delete one or more visitors.

I have created a third table `events_log` for logging actions like edit/delete:

Visitors_log

```
id | userId | visitorId | action
```

This table stores information about user who did actions over table `visitors`.

Which relationship should be between table `visitors_log` and rest two: `users` and `visitors`?

Now I have this Db scheme:

[image]

My opinion is: `visitors_log` can have one or more rows. So relations is one to many. In the same time `visitors_log` can contain one or more users. So, where I am wrong? Now it is one to one relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a possibility that the `user_id` of a visitor could ever change ?

If the answer is yes, then you would better take the safe approach and have two foreign keys in the log, referencing the concerned visitor *and* the user that commited the action.

In MySQL :

```
CREATE TABLE visitors_log (
    idVisitorLog INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    idVisitor    INT NOT NULL,
    idUser       INT NOT NULL,
    action       VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    date_action  DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (idVisitorLog),
    FOREIGN KEY (visitor_log_idVisitor) REFERENCES visitors(idVisitor),
    FOREIGN KEY (visitor_log_idUser)    REFERENCES users(idUser)
);
```

PS : you probably want a date column too in the log table, I added one.

---

On the other hand, if the user a visitor is assigned to can never change over time, then your design can be simplified. In the log table, you could just store a foreign key to the visitors table. As the visitor stores a (fixed) user id, you do not need to duplicate that information in the log.